# Cannot connect to my first User in Oracle (SYSTEM)

Tags: oracle

**Hello everyone !**

I'm having trouble to connect to my first user (SYSTEM).
I just did a fresh install on another computer of mine.

After the install and the password set for the user SYSTEM, I tried the command : `SQLPLUS`

Then I put the name of my user and the password.

But everytime I have this error (I'm 100% sure this is the correct password)

[image]

After further research, a lot of people fixed this problem by changing the line :

- `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)` ; In the sqlnet.ora

TO

- `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)`

But of course, by changing this line another error code appear :

[image]

By making this post I hope someone can help me solve this problem for good !
I don't want to change things on my own. (Things that I don't truly understand and I feel this will break my Oracle even more.

Answer (score 0):

`ORA-01034` means that the database isn't up. Start it. How? If it is MS Windows, go to "Services" and start Oracle services.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I Checked my services, and all of them are up.
(OracleServiceXE, OracleMTSRecoveryService, OracleJobScheduleXE, OracleXEClrAgent and OracleXETNSListener).

Comment: Try to `sqlplus / as sysdba` on the operating system command prompt; should *let you in*. Then run `startup`. What happens?

Comment: This is getting very difficult ... 
When I made the command "sqlplus / as sysdba" I got this error :
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges.
And then it ask to enter the user-name.
I don't understand why I don't have those privileges.

Comment: Operating system user should be the one you used to install Oracle, as it then "owns" that "installation" so - using `sqlplus /` tells Oracle: "OK, you're the owner, I know you and I'll let you in". So: are you using that particular operating system user?

Comment: I installed Oracle from a setup.exe given by my high school to be able to use it.
So yes, I used the Operating System user you're telling me.
I hope I answered your question, I don't want to waste your time.

Comment: Did you try to restart the computer? Many IT problems are fixed that way :)

Comment: Ahaha, yeah I  can give it a shot. Be right back

Comment: before running SQL Plus, try doing "set ORACLE_SID=XE" so we know that is the instance you are trying to connect to

Comment: So even by restarting my computer, nothing have change.
I also do your command Connor McDonald.
I have no clue :S
Even if my problem remain, thank you all the for your help and your time :)

If you have other idea, i gladly take it

Comment: Did you check whether Oracle services started after rebooting?

Comment: Yep, they were all enabled after the reboot. I even try to stop them and to active them back.

Comment: Huh. No further ideas at the moment, I'm afraid ... Sorry for not being able to help. I hope someone else will assist.

Comment: Thanks anyway for helping me ! The post will stay for a little while, hoping to have a solution.
Have a nice day and thanks again ! :)